# Collection throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, exception, collections

I am getting an UnsupportedOperationException when calling `add()` in the following code:

```
Collection<MyClass> myClass = method();
MyClass newObject = new MyClass();
myClass.add(newObject);
```

`method()` returns `Collection<MyClass>`.

Also, what should I do if method returns null or an empty Collection?

Comment: What does `method()` returns exaclty?

Comment: it returns Collection<MyClass>

Comment: I know, but what is the concrete implementation you return. Ex: `static Collection<MyClass> method(){ return Collections.emptyList();}` would demonstrate the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: `Collection` is an interface, so no Object of that type can be created. Some other classes, e.g. `ArrayList` or `Set` implement the `Collection` interface and those can be created and returned here.

Comment: ZouZou : Please don't complicate it. Its not a static implementation. It's an honest-to-earth method returning Collection<MyClass>

Comment: @blalasaadri : method() is a third-party API. I have no idea what it returns.

Comment: @qualtar Even if it's static or not that's not the point. Just show what you return. You don't return a `Collection`, you return a concrete implementation of a Collection and without showing what it is, we cannot answer.

Comment: @qualtar In that case you have a problem. It may be an unmodifiable (also called immutable) collection that's returned. Those *shouldn't* be added to - that's the whole point. You can copy the elements from that collection to a new one however which you will be able to modify.

Comment: @ZouZou and balasaadri : makes sense.... i'll check that...

Comment: it returns java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList

Comment: @qualtar So you certainly do `return Collections.unmodifiableList(...);`, which is an unmodifiable list.

Comment: @ZouZou : can be the case....

Comment: @qualtar Do you have access for the code of `method()`? If yes just check what does it return, if not it should be documented elsewhere.

Comment: @ZouZou: that's not required i got the class using Todd's answer....n little wonder u got the talkative badge... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that the method is choosing to return a read-only collection. If you want to add additional items, you will need to create a new collection from it. For example:

```
List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<>(method());
things.add(new Thing());
```

Answer (score 4):

Per the javadocs, [some `Collection`s do not support the `add()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) and since `Collection` is just an interface, you need to  look to see what implementation type the `Collection` is. You can do this in a debugger or with `myClass.getClass().getName()`

Comment: supper....i am expecting it will return some implementation like ArrayList or LinkList ......

Comment: That is doubtful since both of those support `add()`.

Comment: Then I guess you have your answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Once you find out what type method() returns, you should either (1) create a class that extends method()'s type and implements the add() method, initializing myClass to an object of that class.  (2) Cast method()'s return object to another type of class that implements add().  I recommend (1) to preserve the other functionalities in method()'s return class.

Comment: (1) There's no need to create a new class, as there are plenty of useful general-purpose collection classes. (2) Casting an object doesn't change the type of the underlying object, only the type of the variable you use to refer to the object, so casting can't change the behavior of an object's methods.